# Pandas DataFrame export to csv invalid slice error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export

I am baffled as to why this code does not run. A simple example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"var1" : [5], "var2" : [2]})
df.to_csv("csv_file.csv")
```

this code give the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1136, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1171, in save
    self._save()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1277, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1289, in _save_chunk
    date_format=self.date_format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 552, in to_native_types
    values = values[:, slicer]
IndexError: invalid slice
```

NOTE:

It's the final line, `df.to_csv("csv_file.csv")` that gives the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a likely bug that has been fixed as of recent versions of `pandas`, namely, in version `0.16.2`:

```
df.to_csv("csv_file.csv")
```

Works as expected and outputs `csv_file.csv` in the working directory. If you encounter this bug check your pandas version with:

```
import pandas; print(pandas.version.version)
```

and if you're working with an older version use `pip -U --force-reinstall pandas` for `Py2` or `pip3 -U --force-reinstall pandas` for `Py3` to upgrade to the most recent version.

Comment: upgrading to the latest version of pandas, as well as reinstalling pandas for Python 3 (as some of the dependencies between Python2 and Python3 may have been messed up) using `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas` fixed the problem